# How can I get Express to realize there was an error with my Teradata database call?

Tags: javascript, sql, express, teradata

Currently I have Express running a call against my Teradata database and it acts/performs perfectly when everything works.

However if my Teradata call returns an error I see an output in my console window but I cannot setup an error handler.

I realize this should be extremely basic but I am very new to Express. Any help would be appreciated.

Express Call code:

```js
router.post('/sp_run', function (req, res) {
    var sql = "CALL DB.STORED_PROC1(1,P_ERROR_CODE,P_MSG);";
    console.log(sql);
  return teradata.read(sql)
      .then((x) => {
        console.log(x);
   res.send(x);
      });
  });
```

Error info I see in my console.

```js
CALL DB.STORED_PROC1(1,P_ERROR_CODE,P_MSG);
express_1  | 2019-6-27 21:07:10 - error: [Teradata] Unable to execute query: CALL DB.STORED_PROC1(1,P_ERROR_CODE,P_MSG);
express_1  | Unhandled rejection Error: Error running instance method
express_1  | java.sql.SQLException: [Teradata Database] [TeraJDBC 16.20.00.10] [Error 7627] [SQLState HY000] STORED_PROC1:SELECT-INTO returned more than one row.
```

**End game result -- if an error occurs I want to send an email and to send a response back so my front-end isn't just waiting for ever.**

Comment: Use a `try/catch` block to surround the code that errors. Use the `catch` to setup and send the error. - Alternatively, chain `.catch()` on the Promise chain and deal with the error there (preferred).

Comment: Thanks for reaching out -- if I chain the .catch() how could I pass the error to display in a console.log?

Comment: The `catch(err)` should be passed the error if the Promise is constructed properly. so insde `.catch(err){ console.log(err);}`

Answer (score 0):

We can't send promise from here so just send response with status variable with type boolean
then apply condition on frontend

```
 router.post('/sp_run', function (req, res) {
     var sql = "CALL DB.STORED_PROC1(1,P_ERROR_CODE,P_MSG);";
     console.log(sql);

     return teradata.read(sql)
       .then((x) => {
          return res.json({
                   status: true,
                  message: 'All work fine',
                  result: x
              })
        }).catch(error => {
         //send email about failure
          return res.json({
                 status: false,
                 message: 'Failed',
                 error: error.message
           })
       });
    });
```

Or you can send res with status code and handle using try/catch

On front end

```
const getData = () => {
    // Here axios is use for call a api you can use fetch or anthing.
    axios.post('/sp_run', {}).then(data => {
        if(!data.status) {
            alert(data.error)
        } else {
        // Play with data
        }
    })

}
```